# Check which browsers JavaScript code will work on

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, static-code-analysis

How can I check which browsers my JavaScript code (which contains some jQuery) will work on?

For example, is there any way to analyse a piece of code, have it detect that it contains `forEach`, and indicate that it doesn't work with certain versions of Internet Explorer?

Comment: In many cases feature detection is preferred over browser detection. This articles might be usefull [Feature & Browser Detection](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/feature-browser-detection/) and [How to Detect Features Instead of Browsers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: There are a lot of sites - here's a comprehensive one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

Comment: @MarianC I'm not asking about how to detect which browser is running a piece of JS code.

Comment: some IDEs have this info built in, dreamweaver for example.

Comment: @nril yeah, but I want something more automated!

Comment: What's the rationale for what you are trying to do?  If you have code that has to run in older browsers, then a simple way to deal with it is to just polyfill the missing functionality.